# Add angularjs directive to a native html element (input text, div, span etc)?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I have something like this -

```
<input type="text" value="" title="Title"> ...
```

How can I add my custom directive as attribute to the existing html element on the page, let's say - directive as `categoryLookup` -

```
<input type="text" value="" title="Title" category-lookup> ...
```

I need to do this dynamically on page load, i.e make the input text behave per directive logic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here.  You can't "dynamically add" angular directives to already rendered DOM elements without recompiling the DOM, angular will never be able to load them properly.

Comment: "Dynamically add attribute on page load". Is there a specific reason why you want to do this? The Angular way would be to simply add `category-lookup` to the `input` tag in HTML template and define your directive to bring it to life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with leveraging [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) after targeting your element. I added an `id` and used vanilla JS in this example, but you may have more at your disposal e.g. jQuery. After you have your element, just `$compile` it in your associated controller. Observe the following example...

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" title="Title"> 
</div>
```

---

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $compile) {
    $compile(angular.element(document.getElementById('myInput')).attr('category-lookup', 'category-lookup'))($scope)
})
.directive('categoryLookup', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log('directive registered')
        }
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/0hvoy3vg/) - demo

---

Also, "dynamically on page load" can mean a *few things*. I assumed you are in a fully fleshed out AngularJS ecosystem, but there does exist the notion that you do not even have a controller and need to somehow cherrypick this directive and compile it on "load". Here is a nitty gritty example how you can do so, though, it's generally regarded as a bad practice, and instead leveraging the above logic in an associated controller is preferable. Observe the following...

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" value="" title="Title"> 
</div>
```

---

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {

    var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'app']);

    $injector.invoke(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        $compile(angular.element(document.getElementById('myInput')).attr('category-lookup', 'category-lookup'))($rootScope)
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/1zv1edy3/) - demo - no controller

Comment: Yes, $compile is what did the trick. demo 1 worked for me. I injected '$compile' into the directive to the compile the html template. Thank you very much :-)